# List out the related values corresponding in other column

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evGjU.jpg)

As you see we have to fetch the related values corresponding to the item column in values column in pyspark

Comment: Have you tried any approach and got an error/blocker?

Comment: Tried by using group by and pivot function

Answer (score 0):

As per the above data. I created a sample data frame `df`.

```
+----+-----+
|item|value|
+----+-----+
|   1|    9|
|   2|    8|
|   3|    7|
|   1|    2|
|   2|    1|
|   1|    3|
|   2|    2|
+----+-----+
```

I reproduce the same thing in my environment with the group by and pivot function with agg. I got this output.

**code:**

```
p_df1 = df.groupBy("item").pivot("item").agg(collect_list("value"))
p_df1.show()
```

[image]

As per your requirement. Select columns 1, 2, and 3 from the data frame using the `select()` method.

```
output1 = [list(row) for row in p_df1.select("1", "2", "3").collect()]
output1 = [[x for x in row if x] for row in output1]
print(output1)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something as below (using builtin `pyspark` functions) -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data = [(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["item", "value"])

df_agg = df.groupBy("item").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_list("value")).alias("values"))

pivot_df = df_agg.groupBy().pivot("item").agg(first("values"))
final_df = pivot_df.select(col("1"), col("2"), col("3"))

final_df.show()

+-----+-----+---+
|    1|    2|  3|
+-----+-----+---+
|9,2,3|8,1,2|  7|
+-----+-----+---+
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer. Upvote too, if you like.